# Angular ng-grid issue

Tags: ng-grid

I am trying to use ng-grid using the following tutorial.

```
http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/
```

Here is my View

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular-resource.js")"></script>
@*<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>*@
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ng-grid-2.0.7.min.js")"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/PostsController.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/postreq.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/ng-grid.min.css" />
<div data-ng-controller="PostsController">
    <div class="gridStyle" data-ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my Angular code

```
function PostsController($scope, $http) {
    $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/request' }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.posts = data;       

        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.error = "An Error has occured while loading posts!";
            $scope.loading = false;
        });

    $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'posts' };
}
```

However, when i run the application i see blank square in browser and there is no error showing in the console.
Please help me to fix this issue.

FYI: I checked API response directly in browser and it shows with data.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are missing some steps of the tutorial you are following :

> Where you declare your app module, add ngGrid:
>    `angular.module('myApp',['ngGrid']);`

I do not see your module declaration anywhere.

Comment: Is it mandatory to achieve ngGrid functionality using Angular modules? I am not using Angular Modules and just trying to use it using simple Angular functions as i have shown in my code.

Comment: "Most applications have a main method which instantiates, wires, and bootstraps the application. Angular apps don't have a main method. Instead modules declaratively specify how an application should be bootstrapped." - http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ng-app="myApp" defined at the top of your page?

I also noticed that you do not have a css class defined for "gridStyle".  "gridStyle" is not part of the ng-grid css.

Comment: In my Layout.cshtml
i do have data-ng-app

    <html data-ng-app="" lang="en">

but still no success.
A square bracket comes with empty contents.
Here is my css

    .gridStyle {
        border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
        width: 400px; 
        height: 300px;
    }

and here is reference

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Site.css" />

Answer (score 0):

Sounds odd, but this worked for me by using a timeout. Try it like this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $http.get('/api/request')
        .success(function (data, status) {
            $scope.posts = data;
        })
        .error(function (data, status) {
            alert(status);
        });
}, 100);
```